# Custom field for category in prestashop 1.5.4

Tags: php, field, prestashop

I'm trying to add a new custom field to a category in prestashop 1.5.4 and a new image field.

I'm looking for solution but nothing seems to help.

This is what I have done this far: http://wklej.org/id/1081777/

Comment: Tell us, what you already tried.

Comment: alter table ps_categories and add a new field

Answer (score 0):

Alter table ps_categories and add a new field

Comment: heh i have done it ... i add new field in ps_categories_lang because there we have e.g. description. if you look on my code i add it into controller too. ;) and it still not save any content into field description2